# Why Multicast is not working properly in Android

Tags: android, multicast, multicastsocket

I am trying to discover my app on a network. So I choose `multicast` technology. But it's inconsistent in Android.

## Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```

## Lock multicast filter

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
mcastLock = wifiManager.createMulticastLock("SHAREALL_M_LOCK");
mcastLock.acquire();
```

## Sending multicast

```
MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket();
socket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.5"));
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(msg, msg.length, InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.5"), 8092);
socket.send(packet);
```

## Receiving multicast

```
MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(8092);
socket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.5"));
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data,data.length);
socket.receive(packet);
```

I have tested these code in Samsung Gallaxy SII and Moto G.

Comment: This is a *statement*: "Multicast is inconsistent in Android." There's nothing to *answer* there. If you have a *question*, please try to make that clear and you may find some help.

Comment: Agree that you should ask a question.  However, I can comment that multicast sending is simply not available on some android devices.   Specifically, I have found that multicast sockets do not work on some Motorola droids.  The same exact code works fine on other devices.